# Best practice to load config file in python

Tags: python-3.x, configparser

I am going to read data from a config.ini file using configparser, but I'm wondering what the best practice is.

Should I:

1. Load the config file once in my main method when the application starts, then call the variable in other modules (something like the below):

   ```
   from main import config
   ```
2. import configparser in each module where I need information from the config file (I feel like this is not the right way because I would have the same code in multiple places).

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: You are missing one alternative: "1½. Load the config file once in my main method when the application starts, then pass the configuration to other modules." (Or rather "/.../ pass parts of the configuration to classes or functions in other modules.")

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what the difference is. I 1½, I'd still be doing `from main import config` I guess?

Comment: No, in the file containing `main` you would use `import other_module` and then in `main` you would use `other_module.some_function(configuration)`.

Comment: I see. Is it best practice to import into main, rather than import from main?

Comment: But what are you passing `configuration` as? Let's say in main I `from config import configparser` and I create a instance called `configuration`. If I now pass that to `other_module.sum_function(configuration)`, while the other module, won't I also need to `from config import configparser` so that the module can know the methods and variables of the `configuration` that's passed in?

Answer (score 0):

You can `from configparser import configparser` in one module, and use that to extract the configuration information from a file.

Then put that information into built-in python data structures which can be passed to the other modules and the classes and functions within those modules.

If you do this in your `main.py`, then you only need to import it into the main module. What you pass into the other modules, classes, or functions you might pass as dictionaries or more complex structures as needed.

I think that's what @md2perpe might have been getting at in his comment on your question. `configparser` never needs to be known in any other modules if you're passing in just the data that you extracted from it.